# Hashing function

Tags: c++

Whats the best way to calculate a hash key for an integer when writing a hashtable.i am thinking of writing `int hashkey= key%arraysize`
    From my research my above example should only be done on prime array sizes

Comment: Depends on the range(s) of values that the int will contain. In the general case, multiplying with a large **odd** number before the modulo operation will give sufficient spread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should select a prime number as the array size, and use value%arraysize as the hash key.

Comment: @Oli: we have a case of prime number voodoo here.

Comment: I can't provide a perfect justification, but that's what GCC's hash tables do.

Comment: Maybe gcc hashes strings with a subobtimal hashfunction, (such as elf)

Comment: Prime numbers have advantages for quadratic probing hash tables, IIRC, but not for hash tables in general.

Comment: but i want the size of my array to to be any number.

Comment: Using prime number is recommended for better uniformity. Theoretically, you can use any number as the array size, but the element distribution varies for different array sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the std hash.It's better.

```
std::size_t myHash = std::cout << std::hash<int>{}(myInt);
```